# Can we use "#elif !" in c?

Tags: c, gcc

I am confused by the code in sprng2.0 and it gives me compile errors on my machine after I make. It seems that my compiler(gcc 4.7.3) doesn't support `#elif !`, what does `#elif !` mean? Or could I just replace it with `#ifndef` ?

```
#ifdef SYNC
if(expJ[dE]>sprng(genptr[k]))
#elif !SYNC
if(dE<=0 || expJ[dE]>sprng(genptr[k]))
#endif
```

The error message is `error: operator '!' has no right operand`
I have tested,

```
#ifdef SYNC
if(expJ[dE]>sprng(genptr[k]))
#elif !(SYNC)
if(dE<=0 || expJ[dE]>sprng(genptr[k]))
#endif
```

It gives me the error: `missing expression between '(' and ')'`

Comment: Personally I don't use `#ifdef` precisely because of this inconsistency, I just use `#if defined(...)`, `#elif defined(...)`, etc.. makes things much more straightforward imho, even if it's a bit more verbose.

Comment: It's not a macro, it's a preprocessor directive. You need to use `defined(SYNC)` to check if a macro is.. well... defined. Also, in your second case, the macro will never be defined, so the extra check is superfluous.

Comment: `if X .... elif !X ...` looks a bit a bit redundant redundant.

Comment: @StoryTeller yeah, It's not macro, it's preprocessor directive. I don't know whether #elif $(SYNC) equals $if !define(SYNC).

Comment: Please update your question to show us the exact error message.

Comment: @n.m. I am confused too. However, is the code in sprng2.0(a random number generating lib), I don't know what is the exact meaning of "#elif !SRNC" and does it equal to "#ifndef SRNC"?

Comment: #elif is contraction of #else #if, there is no such thing as #elifdef for gcc. did it exists for other compilers ? not even sure.

Comment: @philippelhardy: I've never heard of an `#elifdef` extension. Even if it existed, I wouldn't use it, since it would make the code non-portable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code in your question:

```
#ifdef SYNC
/* ... */
#elif !SYNC
/* ... */
#endif
```

may or may not work. It will fail in the way you indicate if the macro `SYNC` is defined as nothing (not undefined, but defined to expand to a sequence of no tokens).

But it's an odd way to write it.

`#ifdef SYNC` tests whether `SYNC` is defined or not, without regard to *how* it's defined.

`#elif !SYNC` tests whether `SYNC` expands to an expression with a *false* value. If `SYNC` is not defined at all, the preprocessor will expand the identifier `SYNC` to `0`, and `#elif !0` is perfectly legal. But if `SYNC` is defined to expand to something that's not a valid operand of `!`, then you'll get an error.

For example, if I compile the above with either `gcc ...` or `gcc -DSYNC ...` (the latter defines `SYNC` as `1`), then there's no error, and I get either the first or the second block of code.

But if I compile it with `gcc -DSYNC= ...`, which defines `SYNC` as an empty token sequence, then the `#elif` expands to:

```
#elif !
```

which is a syntax error. Adding parentheses doesn't help; it just changes the error message.

The real problem, I think, is that you're mixing a test for whether `SYNC` is defined or not with a test for whether its value is true or false.

You very probably don't need the `#elif`; just `#else` will do.

If you want to choose which chunk of code to compile based on whether `SYNC` is defined, just write:

```
#ifdef SYNC
/* ... */
#else
/* ... */
#endif
```

If you want to test whether `SYNC` is true or false (and noting that if `SYNC` is not defined as a macro it expands to `0`), you can write:

```
#if SYNC
/* ... */
#else
/* ... */
#endif
```

You can use either form, but I personally would prefer the `#ifdef` (unless there's some meaningful distinction between different defined values of `SYNC`).

Note that the preprocessor has `#ifdef` and `#ifndef` directives, but it doesn't have `#elifdef` or `#elifndef` (but the upcoming C23 standard, not yet published as I type this, will add them). If you need to test for definedness in a `#else`, just use the `defined` operator:

```
...
#elif defined(SYNC)
...
```

But I don't think you need to do that in this case.

Comment: Note that `#elifdef` and `#elifndef` are now introduced in C++23, could desserve an update.

Comment: They're introduced in C23. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest would be

```
#ifdef SYNC
defined
#else
undefined
#endif
```

Or closer to your code:

```
#ifdef SYNC
defined
#elif !defined SYNC
undefined
#endif
```

Comment: I will make the code compile successfully. I didn't know the exact meaning of the code #elif !SYNC, since they are the code in an open source library.

Comment: `!SYNC` assumes `SYNC` is defined to zero which is different than not being defined at all. This looks like poorly written code. Also `#if` and `#ifdef` are too different things

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
#ifdef SYNC
defined
#elif !(SYNC)
undefined
#endif
```

Now running preprocessor `gcc -E test.c` outputs:

```
undefined
```

Note: you could also use `#if (SYNC)`, which would have the same effect as `#ifdef`.

Comment: Does #elif !(SYNC) just equal to #ifndef SYNC? What about #define SYNC 0, will it be defined or undefined or neither?

Comment: `#elif (SYNC)` equals to `#ifdef`, if SYNC would be 0, it is still defined and therefore the conditiion will be true.

Comment: I get error: missing expression between '(' and ')' after I modify it to #elif !(SYNC)

Comment: @notbad I am sorry but your chunk of code compiles fine for me.

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: @self.This question is tagged with gcc, so why are you talking about non-gcc compiler ? which one ?

Comment: @Zaffy Fair enough. Didn't notice that requirement.

Comment: That's essentially the same as the code in the question, except for the unnecessary parentheses.

Comment: @KeithThompson The question was edited several times, by the way the parentheses **are necessary** - you will get totally different result with and without.

Comment: @Zaffy: The parentheses affect the error message, but I don't think it affects the behavior in cases where it's correct.

Comment: @Zaffy -- unless the macro has some odd definition like `x + y`, but in that case the macro definition *should* be fully parenthesized.